# [boxx][boxy] Syntax error

Tags: python

I am learning how to code in python with pygame using a book, so I am writing down the code. Yet when I run it, it gives me a syntax error on revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True, I'm 
                                                                   ^
not sure what the problem is. Thank you greatly if you could help!

Here is the code:

```
if boxx != None and Boxy != None:
        if not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy]:
            drawHighlightBox(boxx, boxy)
        if not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] and mouseClicked:
            revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)]
            revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True
```

Comment: What's the snippet of code that you're using to do that?  Further to that, is `revealedBoxes` either a list of lists, or a dictionary of dictionaries that would allow you to access the data?

Comment: Show us the code, particularly the line where the error is reported and the line directly above that line.

Comment: Wow falsetru how did you edit it like that?

Comment: @Dominico909, Select the code, and press Ctrl + K  or click *Code Sample* button above the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)]
```

You dropped a parenthesis here.

Comment: Yay thank you, that really was the problem. But what confuses me is that I used a thing online that checks how different your code was to that of the book(like if there are any typing mistakes), and nothing showed up. And how do I mark that the problem was solved? And really, thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid statement

```
>>> revealedBoxes = [[True]]
>>> boxx, boxy = 0, 0
>>> revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True
```

unless it is used as expression in `while`, `if`, ...:

```
>>> if revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True: pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True: pass
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> while revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True: pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    while revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True: pass
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Did you mean `==` ?

```
>>> if revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] == True: pass
...
```

**UPDATE**

The code is missing `)`.

```
        revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)]  # <----
        revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True
```

Comment: if not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] and mouseClicked:
    revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)]
    revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True          This is my code. It was written down exactly like that in the book.

Comment: @Dominico909, It's hard to read your code in the comment. Please add the code in your question (not in the comment).